# How web server knows that HTTP request is addressed to it?

Tags: http, ip, webserver, port

So I know that ports are assigned to each program and the HTTP port is `80`(or `443` if secure) and if I will send some request via browser to something like `google.com` it will get the IP from the DNS server + the default HTTP port and thus it will send GET request to `8.8.8.8:80/`. But for example Tomcat has a default port `8080`.

So the question is: How Tomcat can resolve that the message is addresed to it and not some other application that is also running on the same server and listening to HTTP port?

I looked up several articles about the HTTP requests, ports, and a way how request travels through the internet and the system but did not find an answer.

EDIT 1:
I asked ChatGPT and it told me about Reverse Proxy Server (e.g., Apache or Nginx): This server sits in front of your application servers and handles incoming requests from clients. It listens on the standard HTTP port 80 or HTTPS port 443. The reverse proxy's primary function is to route requests to the appropriate backend application servers based on various rules and configurations. But it would be nice to hear another opinion on that from you guys :)